# Android custom edittext with line design like in notepad

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to make a custom edittext with lines like in a note pad. The biggest issue ive met that it breaks the line and doesn't draw it properly.

```
    public class NoteEditText extends EditText {
        private final int heightpixels;
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Rect mRect;
        private Canvas canvas;


        public NoteEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs,
                    R.styleable.NoteEditText,
                    0, 0);

            this.heightpixels = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            this.mRect = new Rect();
            this.mPaint = new Paint();
            this.mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            try {
                mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(a.getString(R.styleable.NoteEditText_lineColor)));
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            }
        }

        public NoteEditText(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.heightpixels = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            this.mRect = new Rect();
            this.mPaint = new Paint();
            this.mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int count;
            this.canvas = canvas;
            int lineheight = getLineHeight();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getText())) {
                count = (this.heightpixels / lineheight) + 2;
            } else {
                count = getLineCount();
            }
            Rect r = this.mRect;
            Paint paint = this.mPaint;
            int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                canvas.drawLine((float) r.left, (float) (baseline + 1), (float) r.right, (float) (baseline + 1), paint);
                baseline += lineheight;
            }
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawForeground(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDrawForeground(canvas);
    }
}
```

This often happens when you try to add text in new lines and try to delete.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyvKV.png)

Here is XML also

```
<com.example.dev.customedittext.NoteEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorHint="#AAAAAA"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:lineColor="#000000"
    />
```

Are there any suggestions how to fix this issue ?

Comment: To help we might like to know a little more is the error that the text is not being drawn one line after another? So you want no spaces between the drawn text? Do you mind telling us why you picked the canvas to draw text on? If you only want text on the screen with some formatting control would you consider a multi line EditText widget

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<com.testing.remon.LineEditText
android:id="@+id/edit1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:background="@null"
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
android:minLines="10"
android:singleLine="false"
android:imeOptions="actionNone"
/>
```

**Below is custom EditText Class**.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0x800000FF);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 2, r.right, baseline + 2, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

}
```